# Como ler um arquivo em Prisma?

Tags: prisma

Estava tentando ler um arquivo em Prisma mas não encontro a função correta:

```lua
local arquivo = 'arquivo.txt'
imprima(arquivo)
```

Em lua, seria algo como `local file = 'file.txt'; print(file);`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Em Lua

O código abaixo lê o conteúdo completo de um arquivo:

```lua
arquivo = 'arquivo.txt'
handle = io.open(arquivo, "r")
conteudo = handle:read("*a")
handle:close()
print(conteudo)
```

Se você quiser tratar erros (recomendado!), use algo como

```lua
handle,message = io.open(nome, "r")
if handle==nil then error(message) end
```

### Em Prisma

Em [Prisma](http://linguagemprisma.br4.biz/blog/sobre/) o código é parecido, basta traduzir palavras-chave, nomes de métodos e opções:

```lua
arquivo = 'arquivo.txt'
handle = es.abra(arquivo, "leitura")
conteudo = handle:leia("*t")
handle:feche()
imprima(conteudo)
```